# AngularFire $asArray: Is $add() method like JavaScripts push() method regarding order?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

When I use the $add() method with an [syncronized array in AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-arrays), is that like javasripts push? Meaning that it will be in the end of the array? If so, does that mean that the $add() method is setting $priority, or perhaps the generated keys are created in such a way that it can be used for ordering the array in similar chronological order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularFire's `$add` method ends up calling Firebase's regular `push` method. And that method generates keys that are indeed chronological. The main difference between Firebase's `push` and the regular `Array.push` of JavaScript is that the Firebase has logic to ensure that the keys will be unique even when multiple clients are adding data at the same time.

Calling `push` does *not* set the priority of the node; it relies on the natural order of the *keys*. So you can still use priority for something else. :-)